# Cant get to website past redirection

Tags: java

I have this link:
http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna

And I need to access the source through Java.
However when i visit the site, I get the contents in czech. There is a button to change the language to english, however using the link from the button gives me an error.

Is there some way I could access the english version of the site?

Thanks

The code I have:

```
    String line = null;
    String kanEngPageHtml = null;

    String kanEngLink = "http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna";
    URL kanEngUrl = new URL(kanEngLink);
    URLConnection kanEngCon = kanEngUrl.openConnection();
    InputStream kanEngIs = kanEngCon.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader kanEngBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kanEngIs,"UTF-8"));

    while ((line = kanEngBr.readLine()) != null) {
        kanEngPageHtml = kanEngPageHtml + "\n" + line;
    }

    System.out.println(kanEngPageHtml);
```

Ok, so I seem to have figured it out. The key was my old macro from VBA, in which I call GET request first to http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/2#menu and then to http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna. So I thought I could try the same.

The key was taking cooking from the first connection and putting them inside the second one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String kanEngLink;
    URL kanEngUrl;
    URLConnection kanEngCon;
    String cookiesHeader;
    InputStream kanEngIs;
    BufferedReader kanEngBr;
    String line;
    String kanEngPageHtml="";

    kanEngLink = "http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/2#menu";
    kanEngUrl = new URL(kanEngLink);
    kanEngCon = (HttpURLConnection) kanEngUrl.openConnection();
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    cookiesHeader = kanEngCon.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

    kanEngLink="http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna";
    kanEngUrl = new URL(kanEngLink);
    kanEngCon = (HttpURLConnection) kanEngUrl.openConnection();
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiesHeader);

    kanEngIs = kanEngCon.getInputStream();
    kanEngBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kanEngIs,"UTF-8"));

    while ((line = kanEngBr.readLine()) != null) {
        kanEngPageHtml = kanEngPageHtml + "\n" + line;
    }

    System.out.println(kanEngPageHtml);
}
```

Comment: Request the site, then request the link from the button, then request the site again, but make sure whatever you're using to request the site maintains the same session, as the language selection is tracked on the website's server, not your browser

Comment: CZ- `http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/1#menu`, EN - `http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/2#menu`

They probably dont have full english version of the site, English menu should be possible acquire by the second link

Comment: I updated the code I have, which at the moment results into czech output.
@zack6849: How would I do this with the code I have? How do I request the site again?

xxxvodnikxxx: Using the second link gives me REFERAL error
<p>Message:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER</p>

Comment: You would need to use some sort of HTTP client for java, what you want is possible with the standard  APIs, but messy and cumbersome

Comment: @zack6849: I see, I would however still want to do it with the standards.
I did something similar with VBA, where i just sent get request to the http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/2#menu and then to http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna

Comment: @zack6849: I have figured it out and edited my post. It is not as messy as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

The key was taking cooking from the first connection and putting them inside the second one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String kanEngLink;
    URL kanEngUrl;
    URLConnection kanEngCon;
    String cookiesHeader;
    InputStream kanEngIs;
    BufferedReader kanEngBr;
    String line;
    String kanEngPageHtml="";

    kanEngLink = "http://www.kanas.cz/language/setlanguage/2#menu";
    kanEngUrl = new URL(kanEngLink);
    kanEngCon = (HttpURLConnection) kanEngUrl.openConnection();
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    cookiesHeader = kanEngCon.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

    kanEngLink="http://www.kanas.cz/stranka/jidelna";
    kanEngUrl = new URL(kanEngLink);
    kanEngCon = (HttpURLConnection) kanEngUrl.openConnection();
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    kanEngCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiesHeader);

    kanEngIs = kanEngCon.getInputStream();
    kanEngBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kanEngIs,"UTF-8"));

    while ((line = kanEngBr.readLine()) != null) {
        kanEngPageHtml = kanEngPageHtml + "\n" + line;
    }

    System.out.println(kanEngPageHtml);
}
```